# Java Regex, how to stop matching when a certain symbol is found

Tags: java, regex, character, match

I recently got into regex stuff. There is something that is bugging me really badly.

How can set my regex to only match certain words IF THERE IS NOT a specific symbol that follows them. 
For example
Say I have a text with some normal words, and some words that end with a capital letter. How do I only get my regex to detect a word, if that word isn't followed by a capital letter.

```
Just some sample texT with wordS. ThiS should be Matched.
```

From this I want my reggex to match all the words, except for "texT, wordS and ThiS".

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in few ways. One could involve [word boundaries `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

`\b` can will match only places which are

- between alphabetic and non-alphabetic characters
- at start or end of input

So to make sure we are matching *whole words* we can surround `\w+` with `\b` like `\b\w+\b`.
Now to make sure that words you found don't end with uppercase letters we can simply require that last character should be lowercase (in range `a-z`).

So we can rewrite our regex to `\b\w+[a-z]\b`

Comment: Hmm this almost solves my problem. (in fact it solves the one I described 100%)..but I was wondering another thing. How would I be able to also ignore words that end in a number. For example "somE#####word21"...
How would I extract "som" and "word" from this ?

Comment: @Kobek Sorry for AFK, had problems with connection. In this particular case you could simply search only for lowercase characters like `[a-z]+`, but something tells me that this may also not be what you *really* want to achieve :)

Comment: @Kobek  But if you think that you asked wrong question and you don't believe that in its current state it will be helpful for anyone, feel free to delete it (I don't mind in this case since based on your comment it looks like another case of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and from my experience editing it lave very low chances of attracting new answers).